# Am I setting up my Jobs Wrong in Quartz.net?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am seeing some errors in my Event Viewer log though from what I can tell everything is working fine though.

I see these 2 errors

The first error happened when I restarted my service (my scheduled job is in a service). I am not sure if I have to do some cleanup or something and that is why I am getting it or what.

Second error I have no clue what it is all about.

```
Application: App.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException
   at Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore.StoreJobInternal(Quartz.IJobDetail, Boolean)
   at Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore.StoreJobAndTrigger(Quartz.IJobDetail, Quartz.Spi.IOperableTrigger, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler+<ScheduleJob>d__82.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Service+<OnStart>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()


  Application: App.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Quartz.SchedulerException
   at Quartz.Impl.SchedulerRepository.Bind(Quartz.IScheduler)
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory+<Instantiate>d__65.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory+<Instantiate>d__65.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory+<GetScheduler>d__69.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Service+<OnStart>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

My code looks like this

```
      protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
            };

            StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);

            var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;



            // get a scheduler
            IScheduler sched = await factory.GetScheduler();
            await sched.Start();



            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
                .WithIdentity("sendJob", "group1") 
                .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("sendTrigger", "group1")
                //.StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 0 12,18 ? * MON-FRI *").InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
                .ForJob("sendJob", "group1")
                .Build();

            // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
            await sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Are you sure that `OnStart` is not called twice?

Comment: have you also got an XML file which loads jobs, perhaps?

Comment: @GuruStron - Well in this app there are 4 other scheduler jobs that do similar things but load different triggers and jobs, All within group1. The code is almost Identical expect for the triggerName, jobName and JobBuilder.Create

Comment: @ADyson - no I do not load it via xml, all my other jobs in this app are setup the same way. All in different services with their own OnStart methods.